# How to programatically export task list data to MPP file in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, export, task-list

How to programatically export task list data to MPP file in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you have integrated Project Web App, then you can directly open the task list.

Another option is to Export the task list to an Excel file. And then import the excel file into MPP.

http://www.tacticalprojectmanagement.com/import-excel-into-microsoft-project/

Comment: i want to export SharePoint Task list data to mpp file programatically.